# Making a file backup program

Tags: c#, arrays, directory

Where I work, I test software, we put a new build of the software on the server each day, I need to be able to save a copy of the build and renaming it for the date it was saved, how would I do this?

(the start and destination locations will be the same each time)

The file is just an installer kinda, it is all self contained.

I need it to access the date the original was created on, so I do not have the problem with multiple files of the same name, and making it easy to find the build I need.

Comment: For fear of being cliched: "what have you tried so far?" Where is the problem?

Comment: I want to save backups of previous builds, because they are deleted from the server when the new build is made, I do not really want to get into arrays, but I will if I absolutely have to.

Comment: @shred1984: You're missing my point. In the simplest terms you just need to copy a directory structure to a different place with a different name. is that a sufficient answer for you? I assume you have thought of this already so maybe you ahve tried to do this and failed. Are you having trouble with the copying? with the scheduling of it to happen? With something else? You might find it easiest to just hook into whatever puts the new build on each day and get it to put it in the standard location and in a directory based on the current date.

Comment: I just want to do this without arrays and such nonsense, I do not have much experience with C#, and almost all of it is with arrays (it may seem strange, but it is true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From msdn:

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string path2 = path + "temp";

try 
{
        // Create the file and clean up handles.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}

        // Ensure that the target does not exist.
        File.Delete(path2);

        // Copy the file.
        File.Copy(path, path2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} copied to {1}", path, path2);

        // Try to copy the same file again, which should succeed.
        File.Copy(path, path2, true);
        Console.WriteLine("The second Copy operation succeeded, which was expected.");
    }
```

Comment: this is the closest thing to an answer I am getting here I think

Comment: I am sure you can create some logic from there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about running perhaps a batch script or vbscript type file to do this automatically?  That's about the easiest way to do it that I can think of.  However, I may be oversimplifying your situation, so just let me know.  I can provide you with some example code on how to do this via a .bat or vbscript file.

Comment: I was going to convert it to Pascal, and make an exe out of it, jus tso I can do it on startup each day

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new folder containing the date in the name (like "Build_2012_06_07") for each build and move all the files (.exe, .dll, .pdb etc.) belonging to a build to this folder without renaming the files.